# Given input size: (512x1x1). Calculated output size: (512x0x0). Output size is too small

Tags: python, machine-learning

There is such an algorithm, I get an error `Size of input data: (512x1x1). Estimated output size: (512x0x0). The output size is too small.` I understand that the problem is in the AvgPool line. Incompatible sizes. I don't understand how to fix this. Tell me please.

```
class AntispoofModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device="cpu", **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        resnet = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)
        self.resnet = nn.Sequential(*[i for i in list(resnet.children())[:-1]]).to(device)
        for ch in self.resnet.children():
            for param in ch.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False
        self.gat = GAT(**kwargs).to(device)
        self.device = device
        self.adj = torch.tensor(grid_to_graph(7, 7, return_as=np.ndarray)).to(device)
        self.avg_pool = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=8, stride=8, padding=0, ceil_mode=False,
                                               count_include_pad=False)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.resnet(x.to(self.device))
        x = self.avg_pool(x)
        #x = x.view(512, -1)
        #x = x.view(512, 1)
        x = self.gat(x, self.adj)
        return torch.sigmoid(x)
        


preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

torch.manual_seed(42)
kwargs = {"nfeat":512, "nhid":64, "nclass":1, "nheads":49, "dropout":0.6, "alpha":0.01}
model = AntispoofModel(**kwargs, device="cpu")

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
```

```
RuntimeError: Given input size: (512x1x1). Calculated output size: (512x0x0). Output size is too small
```

Comment: Dear 12345, you are trying along the way to pool pictures of 1x1 size (512 channels) with a kernel that is 8x8 and a stride of 8. If you calculate the new size of each channel from the formula of the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AvgPool2d.html/) you get to a layer of size 512 channels times 0x0 units. So, there is nothing left by definition of the AvgPool2d you use. You might need to go back to the architecture of your nn. I suggest going through the motions of each layers sizes.

Comment: Thanks. But if I delete ```avgpool``` I have ```mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (512x64 and 512x64)```